# Problems with creating vba macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem when I create macro in one workbook that use another workbook.

This is the code that I am using :

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("
     http://europort/it_division/ITAC/Portal/Documentations/Proba 1.xlsx"
                        )
With wb1
   FinalRow = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
              .Cells(.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1)
              .End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 1 To FinalRow
    If TextBox21.Text = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then 
      MsgBox .Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Text
   Next i
End With
wb1.Close
End Sub
```

It's working fine but it opens another workbook and only when I click OK button it closes that workbook.  I don't want to open this workbook, only to see result and not to see entire excel workbook. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end?

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you work with `MsgBox` it will pause the application until you closed it. Also `.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` has to be in one line or you have to use `_` to make it multi line. Also i would suggest using a variable for the worksheet.

Comment: @UGP That line was in one line, but was changed by one of editors...

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after, based on your question:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
msg = ""
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("http://europort/it_division/ITAC/Portal/Documentations/Proba 1.xlsx")
With wb1
    FinalRow = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        If TextBox21.Text = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
      msg = msg & .Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Text & vbCr
    Next i
End With
wb1.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If msg <> "" Then MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

The whole thing needs tidying up, you should declare etc. but as it stands now if your code works this should also work.